# @Html.AntiForgeryToken Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, dll

It looks like a silly question but i have no way out to pass my error.
I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 5 and everything work fine on my local machine, even i deploy on my local IIS (IIS 7 on Windows 7)
I have a hosting (just a hosting, not a server) and now i deploy on that host and i get the message:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

The error line come from: @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

I have created a fresh mvc 5 project (not add any logic). I just add a simple form with AntiForgeryToken but the issue is still on my host.

So what the relating between Microsoft.IdentityModel and the anti forgery token logic of MVC 5 and does any way i can force MVC getting Microsoft.IdentityModel from my dll not GAC?

I really don't understand what's going on. Could anyone can help me the way to find out more clear and detail about my issue?

Answer (score 1):

set "Copy local" to true in the reference properties for "Microsoft.IdentityModel" in visual studio and try again

Comment: It's still true. After publishing the site, i can see that dll in published folder.